# Center columns using Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a problem with center columns using Zurb Foundation 5.
On the my test page it's not work correctly http://rsketchbook.o12.pl/test/ 
On the snippet it looks good. I don't know what's the difference, what's missing in my code.
Could anyone tell me why it doesn't work on my test page?

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Light';
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoLight.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoRegular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif !important;
}
p,
em,
a {
  font-family: 'Roboto light', sans-serif !important;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em) {
  body > header {
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/7217/landscape-mountains-clouds-trees.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    height: 600px;
  }
  #nav-bar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    height: 84px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .line {
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    transition: height 0.38s ease;
  }
  .menu-item:hover .line {
    height: 4px;
  }
  .menu-item:active .line {
    height: 4px;
  }
  .contain-to-grid,
  .top-bar,
  .top-bar-section ul li,
  .top-bar-section ul li:hover > a,
  .top-bar-section ul li:hover:not(.has-form) > a,
  .top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button),
  ul.right {
    background: none !important;
  }
  #right-nav > ul > li {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  .top-bar-section ul li a {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  #homepage-slogan {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 260px;
  }
  #homepage-slogan h2 {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.0;
  }
  #homepage-slogan hr {
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    height: 6px;
  }
  #homepage-slogan h2,
  #homepage-slogan p {
    color: #000;
    padding-right: 5rem;
  }
}
/* screen min-width: 58.75em  */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-essential/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-essential/5.5.2/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation-essential/5.5.2/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div id="nav-bar" class="fixed">
    <div class="contain-to-grid">
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
        <ul class="title-area">
          <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="logo"></a></h1>

          </li>
          <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
        <section id="right-nav" class="top-bar-section">
          <ul class="right">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <div class="line"></div> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">
                <div class="line"></div>
                Lorem ipsum</a>

            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <div class="line"></div> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <div class="line"></div> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <div class="line"></div> <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section id="homepage-slogan">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-15 columns right">
        <h2 class="text-right">Lorem<br>ipsum lorem</h2>

        <hr>
        <div class="large-14 columns right text-right">
          <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-13 medium-centered columns">
    <div class="medium-6 columns">
      <h3>Center this part</h3>

      <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        <br>
        <br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        <br>
        <br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-1 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-6 columns end">
      <h3>And this in one row</h3>
      test test test test test test test test test test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beware - `Create powerful multi-device layouts quickly and easily with the default 12-column on foundation`- You have on some places `.medium-15`... this is not valid. You have on foundation 1,2,3,...,12 grid columns.

Comment: It's valid. I have generated 15 columns grid with [custom css](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation).

Comment: I am afraid I don't fully understand what exactly do you want to center. But what you can see is that the div where you are using `medium-centered` class is centered.
Just add this to your styles `.medium-13.medium-centered.columns { border: 1px solid #d00; }` to draw a red border around this div. You can see that is centered

Comment: It's centered just when I run code snippet. Two columns below header aren't centered on my **test site** [link](http://rsketchbook.o12.pl/test/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Things -

Not sure it's 100% needed, but I always wrap by columns in a row div, so inside of your centered column, contain the 3 child columns in a row div.

Also, you are only using 13 of the available 15 columns inside the centered column, maybe change the child columns to medium-7 instead of medium-6?

**EDIT -**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-13 medium-centered columns">
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-7 columns">
      <h3>Center this part</h3>

      <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        <br>
        <br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        <br>
        <br>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-1 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-7 columns end">
      <h3>And this in one row</h3>
      test test test test test test test test test test</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to have one column offset on the left and right side. 
The columns must be equal and there must be 1 column space between them.

Comment: Yes, but inside of your 13 column, you reset back to having 15 columns available.  Unless you are saying that you want another offiset inside of your 13 column div?

Comment: So how to do it correctly? It doesn't work.
`<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-13 medium-centered columns">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
              </div>
              <div class="medium-1 medium-centered columns">
              </div>
              <div class="medium-6 medium-centered columns">
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: Added my ideas to my answer

Comment: Thanks, but it's not centered. Please check it on my [test-site](http://rsketchbook.o12.pl/test/) Please look at the **medium-1 columns**. There is still something wrong.

Comment: Looks like you got it, using something like my code! If you are set, be sure yo mark it as answered.